# Can someone help me identify the font used in this logo?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

The image is from the the log for Shin Megami Tensei 20XX. I need help identfiyong the font used for the tetx usd for 20XX. I've tried sites like whatfontis.com, myfonts.com, and likefont.com but have had no luck help would be very much appreciated.

[image]
[image]

Comment: issue is you are using non-global , typically american services, to identify asian fonts. even children can tell you about the trade relations between them. the dev made his own font, maybe. try checking the `assets` folder or `bin` or `lib` where the game is saved.

Comment: @MisterGeeky - whatfontis.com is a Romanian website.  Myfonts is US based. Likefont is Chinese owned and is for identifying Chinese and Japanese fonts. And "Shin Megami Tensei 20XX" is a Japanese game.

Comment: Looks vaguely like Serpentine. That's not it but its stressed sans-serif, action-movie style is close to what you want.

Answer (score 1):

It's an italicized digital data entry font, typically for computer operators.
The ttf file will be available in the game resource folder.
On Windows, you can use the `cd` command on `cmd` to navigating the folder structures.

Comment: I don't know this game but that seems unlikely. The 20XX seems to be part of a static graphic, which wouldn't need to be stored in the game as a font.